# RESTEasy client multipart post file

Tags: java, http, multipartform-data, resteasy

I'm trying to send a file with resteasy client to an http server with some code like this:

```
File source = new File("test.pdf");

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

MultipartFormDataOutput upload = new MultipartFormDataOutput();

upload.addFormData("source", source, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);

Entity entity = Entity.entity(upload, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)
Response response = client.target(url).request().post(entity);
```

What happens is that on the http server I'm not getting the usual "file" in request (with the content, the name etc..), but something like a regular POST parameter named "source" with the file content as its value.
I tried it with some different web servers, so the issue have to be in the request that RESTeasy builds.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

[MultipartFormDataOutput](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/RESTEasy_Reference_Guide/multipart_formdata_output.html) behaves the same away as a HTML form would do. It sends key/value pairs to the server.

If you want to upload a MIME message consider using [MultipartOutput](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.4.Final/userguide/html/Multipart.html#multipart_output).

Comment: Would you consider writing an example of the usage of MultipartOutput?

Comment: @DarkCygnus It's pretty simple. You just add your parts and let RESTEasy take care of it with its *Output providers. You can find examples in one of [RESTEasy's JUnit test](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/testsuite/integration-tests/src/test/java/org/jboss/resteasy/test/providers/multipart/MimeMultipartProviderTest.java). I recently had to send a `multipart/related` message and it worked like a charm - unfortunately I am disallowed to post any sources here